# jQuery UI autocomplete update hidden field with value but display label in UI, in conjunction with ASMX

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asmx, jquery-ui-autocomplete

In the snippet below, how can I get the jquery autocomplete plugin to:

1. Update a hidden field with the UserID
2. Update '#MessageTo' with the full name

I believe I need to use .result, but I can't figure out the syntax.  Please note that I'm using ASMX so I must do a post (don't want to enable security risk)

```
    $("#MessageTo").autocomplete({
        dataType: "json",
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var postParams = "{ pattern: '" + $("#MessageTo").val() + "' }";

            return jQuery_1_7_1.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Services/Users.asmx/GetNames',
                data: postParams,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d.Users, function (c) {
                        return {
                            label: c.FullName,
                            value: c.UserID
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

I see some similar posts but not in conjunction with ASMX.

Comment: What is `d` property for `data.d` ?

Comment: The response (data) contained the useful data in a json object d

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe you are interested in updating other HTML elements on the page, when the user selects something from an autocomplete-enabled textbox - is that right?

The code you have above probably works already, to provide autocomplete "suggestions" as the user types. If I understand correctly, You want to update a few fields after the user accepts one of the suggestion.s

To do that, use the `select` member of the autocomplete options.

```
 $("#MessageTo")
    .autocomplete({
        dataType: "json",
        autoFocus: true,
        minLength: 3,
        source: function (request, response) {
            var postParams = "{ pattern: '" + $("#MessageTo").val() + "' }";

            return jQuery_1_7_1.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                url: '/Services/Users.asmx/GetNames',
                data: postParams,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) {
                    response($.map(data.d.Users, function (c) {
                        return {
                            label: c.FullName,
                            value: c.UserID
                        };
                    }));
                }
            });
        }, 

        select: function (event, ui) {
            var v = ui.item.value;
            $('#MessageTo').html("Something here" + v);
            $('#Hidden1').html("Something else here" + v);
            // update what is displayed in the textbox
            this.value = v; 
            return false;
        }

    });
```

Also: your use of ASMX is irrelevant. From the perspective of autocomplete, it's just a source for data. Also, the use of POST is irrelevant. It is possible to configure ASMX on the server side to allow HTTP GET. It's not a security hole if you enable it. It's just a different way of accepting requests.

The autocomplete box cannot tell if the server side is ASMX or Python, or ASP-classic, or PHP, or anything else. If I have understood the question correctly, your comment that *I  see some similar posts but not in conjunction with ASMX* is irrelevant.

Comment: also, use ui.item.label in order to get the fullname to be displayed in your autocomplete.

Answer (score 7):

You are correct that you want to use the select configuration option - the values you want are passed to your custom function as `ui.item.value` and `ui.item.label`. You can `return false` to prevent the default behaviour and access the target element using `this`. i.e.

```
$("#MessageTo").autocomplete({
   /* Existing code is all OK */

   select: function (event, ui) {
      // Set autocomplete element to display the label
      this.value = ui.item.label;

      // Store value in hidden field
      $('#hidden_field').val(ui.item.value);

      // Prevent default behaviour
      return false;
   }
});
```